# Is this an authentic Hindu yagna?

Tags: yajna

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmWRpP_V5q0

It sounds like a modern composition that imitates authentic Vedic Yagnas.

Comment: "It sounds like a modern composition that imitates authentic Vedic Yagnas." - Yes, you're right. It's not a Vedic yajna.